# winforms setup file dll problem

Tags: c#, winforms, installation

I'm trying to create a setup file in a c# WinForms project. My application contains an external reference (a .dll in my d:\test folder).

When I try to execute the application through Visual Studio it is working fine. After that I created a setup file for the same application.

After install my setup in different machine it is showing an error:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could
>   not load file or assembly
>   'Interop.TextGRABSDKLib,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find
>   the file specified. File name:
>   'Interop.TextGRABSDKLib,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null'

Any thoughts on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Is TextGRABSDKLib your code or is it a third party code you are referencing? (Mostly its some COM code you are referencing. Hence the interop)
If its the former, then you need to check if the dll is copied to your software install location. Else you need to install the third party sdk first as a pre-requisite; then use the software

Comment: Yes it is a third pary fererence. But How can i copy the dll into client system

Comment: Go to the reference -> Right click -> Properties -> Copy Local.
But I would install the runtime of the third party dll on the PC since the dll you referenced may have other dependencies.

Comment: I copied that dll also into the application folder but still it is giving file not found exception

Comment: It can be that the interop is corrupted. Please rebuild the solution & try again.

Also try to install the 3rd party runtime /sdk on the client machine. The dll  TextGRABSDKLib may have some additional dependencies (use dependency walker to find them )

Answer (score 0):

You could try [registering](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/regsvr32.mspx?mfr=true) the dll on the client machine using the command "regsvr32 TextGRABSDKLib.dll" without the quotes at the commandline.